Using relative coordinates with \draw plot
I am trying to do something like this:


\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (offset) at (1,0); 

\draw[domain= 0:360, smooth, variable = \t] plot ($ (offset) + ({cos(\t) },{sin(\t)})$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

However this gives the error that "Package tikz Error + or - expected.
just doing


\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[domain= 0:360, smooth, variable = \t] plot  ({1+ cos(\t) },{sin(\t)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

works fine. But if there is something like the first option, that would be a lot cleaner.
I am doing a circle as an example, but I may swap it out later for a more complicated curve that I would want to shift by some fixed amount.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

You can move this shift arguments to the options of tikzpicture environment. Then this question may be helpful: In a tikzpicture, how can I "shift" by a multiple of the current x-vector (say)?

@zpding: if you shift everything inside a tikzpicture, it would be the same as doing nothing. I do not understand your comment/suggestion.

@hpekristiansen yes, it would be better if i change the tikzpicture to scope. Thanks for pointing out this.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[red] (0,0) circle[radius=2pt];
\coordinate (offset) at (1,0); 
\draw[shift=(offset)] plot[domain=0:360, smooth, variable=\t] ({cos(\t)},{sin(\t)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


